# How to upload file to another directory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I want to store file to another directory. how i configure the filesystems config to point to another directory?

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Directory Structure example:
[image]

My laravel app is on C directory. I want to store the file on Z directory.

Comment: `storage_path` is a method that renders in the OS's version of the current storage folder in laravel. It should render in something like `c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\storage` If you just enter `z:\htdocs\laravel\storage`, it should target that drive/directory. The fact that you can, does not mean you should. Folder permissions might become a problem and you usually should make sure the directory exists before writing to it, otherwise the code can fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `filesystems.php` add to `disk` array:

```
'disks' => [
    'z' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => 'Z:/',
    ],
    // ...
],
```

Then call the storage facade like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// ...

$path = Storage::disk('z')->put('example.txt', 'Contents');
```

Note: As mentioned by @Techno you may need to set the appropriate permissions on the target directory to allow Laravel to write to it.
More info on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#configuration).